# Apigee adding a forward slash in URL

Tags: android, ios, apigee

I'm accessing below apigee configured URL

https://xyzabc.com:9111/oauth2?client_id=zrgst&scope=xyz

when I'm tracing this url at Apigee i'm getting following URL

https://xyzabc.com:9111/oauth2?client_id=zrgst&scope=xyz/

I'm facing this issue of adding a forward slash while I'm accessing URL from iOS phone and my desktop chrome browser.

Due to this extra slash I'm facing a lots of issues, It will be great help if someone can provide solution.

Comment: You may want to try posting this on the Apigee community hub at community.apigee.com

Answer (score 0):

Apigee won't just add that / in unless you have some policy to do so, and if it's coming from the app, it's a non-URL compliant way of passing a slash.

You should URI encode the / to %2F before sending it in, or if your policies are somehow adding it, make sure you escape the characters in a policy.